# Which preposition to use for the phrase "to be studying at"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, preposition

Which preposition should be used to communicate that "I am studying *at* this school"? *Auf*? *Bei*? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Related, perhaps dupe: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/9704/1224

Comment: The question makes little sense unless you specify at least which verb you want to use.

Comment: And, related to the verb choice, whether it is about a high school or university etc.

Answer (score 3):

For primary and secondary education one would not use *studieren* (=study):

> Ich gehe *zu* dieser Schule/diesem Gymnasium.
>
> Ich gehe *in* diese Schule/dieses Gymnasium.
>
> Ich gehe *an* diese Schule/dieses Gymnasium.
>
> Ich gehe *auf* diese Schule/dieses Gymnasium.
>
> Ich besuche diese Schule/dieses Gymnasium.

Higher education (where the word *studieren* applies):

> Ich studiere *an* dieser Universität/Hochschule.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer states, do not use *studieren* for primary and secondary education (*Grundschule*, *Realschule*, *Gymnasium*, *Berufsschule*), but do use it for higher education (*Fachhochschule*, *Universität*).

*to study* can be translated differently:

- lernen (e.g., for a test)
- eine Ausbildung machen (e.g., study at a university to get a degree)

in the first case simply use *lernen an*:

> Ich *lerne an* dieser Schule.
>
> Ich *lerne an* dieser Universität.

in the second case use these:

> Ich *gehe auf* diese Schule.
>
> Ich *studiere an* dieser Universität.

Comment: I think that "lerne" would rarely be used in this sense. I think that "gehe auf" or "besuche" are more common.

Comment: As I said, _lerne an_ would be used if a person is specifically learning something (like learning for a test): _Ich lerne an dieser Schule für den Test_