# Confusion on when to use in, an and auf?

Tags: preposition, usage, standard-german

I am very confused on when to use **an**, **in** and **auf**.

I am using the "Teach yourself complete German" book. In unit 20, in the practicing section, they made an exercise where I must fill the gaps.

It is like this: "..... Nein, wir haben Urlaub ... der Ostsee gemacht, ... der Insel Rügen".

My answer was "..... Nein, wir haben Urlaub **in** der Ostsee gemacht, **in** der Insel Rügen". But in the Solutions section they wrote "..... Nein, wir haben Urlaub **an** der Ostsee gemacht, **auf** Insel Rüge".
Why?

Answer (score 1):

*An* means *near it* and therefore it is the appropriate preposition for *Ostsee*, since you probably spent not the whole time in the water, which *in der Ostsee* would imply.

(I admit, that this is tricky, since Rügen as an isle actually is *in der Ostsee*. For a huge unspecified region as *Südsee* however, *in* may still be appropriate.)

For islands in general *auf* is the preposition to use, while towns, regions and countries would require *in*. *Auf* is further used for conventions, parties etc. I'm afraid, there are just a few rules of thumb, what to use when, see e.g. [lokale Präpositionen](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/lokale-praepositionen.html) under the section *Präpositionen, die auf die Frage "wo" eine Antwort geben können*.

(See also [this related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/9704/1696).)